# How to upgrade to JFrog Artifactory 7.77.x on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, centos7, artifactory

I am trying to upgrade our version of JFrog from 7.33 to 7.77 on CentOS 7 but getting the follow error:

```
Error: Package: jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.77.6-77706900.x86_64 (Artifactory-pro)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
```

Would anyone in the forum have experience with this issue? My initial research/testing has me leading there is no `libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)` for CentOS 7 but going to dive deeper in research now to see.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message

```
Error: Package: jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.77.6-77706900.x86_64 (Artifactory-pro)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
```

take note about [Artifactory System Requirements and Platform Support](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-system-requirements-and-platform-support) which states for RHEL-based systems only 8.x or 9.x and that CentOS 7.x has reached End of Active Support on 2020.

> *... there is no `libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)` for CentOS 7 ...*

Right, that's the case. At least not out-of-box or from the main distributors.

> *... but going to dive deeper in research now to see.*

You could search for the library on [rpmfind.net](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libstdc%2B%2B.so.6%28CXXABI_1.3.9%29%2864bit%29&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=) or [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)) which would lead in the second case to a 3rd-party package provider [ghettoforge.org](https://rhel.pkgs.org/7/ghettoforge-x86_64/gcc10-libstdc++-10.2.1-7.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)

> [*... providing those packages that either are not available elsewhere or newer packages than exist in either your distribution's base package sets or via other repositories.*](http://ghettoforge.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Please read all information on all linked pages carefully, have a backup and tested recovery before using "backported" libraries on your system and prefer an OS upgrade to a v9-branch instead.

**Further Reading**

- [What is backporting, and how does it apply to RHEL and other Red Hat products?](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/what-backporting-and-how-does-it-apply-rhel-and-other-red-hat-products)

Answer (score 0):

JFrog dropped support for CentOS 7, so the latest available version is `7.71.9`

```
# rpm -ivh --test jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.71.9.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]

# rpm -ivh --test jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.77.3.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) is needed by jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.77.3-77703900.x86_64
```

You can get more info - https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-release-information/artifactory-release-notes

```
As part of JFrog commitment to maintain the security and reliability 
of the JFrog Platform, Artifactory will officially run with Node.js 20.x
on all installation types from Artifactory 7.77.3.

Node.js 20.x provided with Linux Archive/Debian/RPM installations 
is not supported on the following operating systems:

RHEL 7.x - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.x (has reached End of Full Support on 2019)
```